# Finding the outer measure of the x-axis in $\mathbb{R}^2$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

I'd like to find the outer measure of the x-axis
$$\{(x,0):x\in\Bbb R\}=:E$$
in $\mathbb{R}^2$ by following the definition, that is, constructing countable collections of rectangles that cover $E$ and taking the infimum over the total area of each collection. Actually, I know $E$ has outer measure $m_*(E)=0$, so the thing is, how do I find a countable collection of rectangles that covers $E$ and allows me to conclude
$$m_*(E)\leq 0$$
in a limiting process? Based on my little experience, I made myself the following rectangles:

[image]

Each rectangle is of unit length and width $2^{-n}$, and $n$ is a fixed positive integer I want to use later in an "$n\to\infty$" argument. Then
$$\Lambda:=\bigcup_{N=1}^\infty\Lambda_N$$
would be a countable collection of rectangles that covers $E$, and we have
$$m_*(E)\leq\sum_{Q\in\Lambda}|Q|=2\sum_{N=1}^\infty(2^{-n}\cdot 1)\color{red}{=}\infty\cdot 2^{-n}.$$
I don't think the last equality would help anyway. Something seems to be wrong. Is there any construction that really works? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take the following set of rectangles:

$$Q_k=[k,k+1]\times\left[-\frac{\epsilon}{2^{|k|}},\frac{\epsilon}{2^{|k|}}\right] \;\;\text{ for each   }\;\; k\in \mathbb{Z}$$

$$m_*(E)\leq \sum\limits_{k\in \mathbb{Z}}|Q_k|= 2\epsilon + 2\sum_{k\geq 1}\frac{\epsilon}{2^{k-1}}=6\epsilon$$

And you can take $\epsilon>0$ arbitrarily small, that is to say, that $m_*(E)\leq 0$.

As you can see, the trick is to make each covering's measure finite and dependant of a free parameter, in this case $\epsilon$.

Comment: Thank you for you kindly help. Your approach is simple yet effective. That's great.

Comment: I'm glad to help :)